# How to set browser cookie that expires every hour

Tags: javascript, python, cookies

I have a website with a python backend and a javascript/html front-end, naturally. There is a certain pop-up that I want to show every hour. It does not matter on which page of the site a user is on; once the popup appears, it should wait for one hour to show up again. I can’t figure out how to create the cookie to do this. Presently the popup is governed by the front-end and it shows up each time a person navigates to a different page on the site. I would prefer to keep the management completely in the front-end. But I don’t mind managing it on the server either. So how to do track that I have already shown the popup to a certain user/browser instance and so wait for another hour before showing it again?

**The key problem for me is that the cookie is for the entire website not just for one web page**

Comment: You want it to respond real-time? Cause to create a cookie which expires after an hour isn't that hard I guess?;) And to trigger an action when a cookie isn't set...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript provides the answer for your question I guess. They set a cookie on the root which expires after one hour.

Comment: Does it really have to expire? I think I would rather remember the time when the last pop-up was shown and calculate the difference. A time-out could be scheduled when the page is loaded. There would still be a problem if the user has more than one tab - the pop-up might show simultaneously in all tabs. Maybe that's not a problem?

Comment: Or you could use local storage to communicate between tabs :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22001740/98057

Comment: For clarification: The idea is that no matter where the user lands (except for the homepage, actually), I show my popup and then wait one hour before showing it again. I image I need to use a cookie to do that. Once the cookie has been set, I want it to be accessible/readable from any other page soever; so that I can check that the popup was already presented and therefore should not be presented again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expires` with your cookie.

```
    # Pseudocode
    var d = new Date(); 
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 60*60*1000); // in milliseconds
    document.cookie = 'foo=bar;path=/;expires='+d.toGMTString()+';';
```

also you can use `max-age` with your cookie.

```
# Pseudocode    
document.cookie = 'foo=bar;path=/;max-age='+60*60+';';
```

Note :
Internet Explorer does not support max-age, so if you want proper cookie persistence cross-browser, then stick to `expires`.

Comment: So you are saying that as long as I set the cookie it will apply to my entire website not just a specific webpage? So that I can check the 'global' cookie from any page in my website?

Comment: you can extend the response header of each page of your website to set cookie for each page.when you are returning response for a page override response header of that page and add above logic

Comment: Now you have lost me. So the idea is that no matter where the user lands (except for the homepage, actually), I show my popup and then wait one hour before showing it again. I image I need to use a cookie to do that. Once the cookie has been set, I want it to be accessible/readable from any other page soever.

Comment: If you will set a cookie while returning response for a page, It will be available for all other pages.