# Is browser's "localStorage.generator++" operator atomic?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to implement a unique ID generator backed by browser's local storage. My concern is that the ++ operator for the storage DOM object is not implemented to run atomically.

Consider:

```js
function generateUniqueID() {
  if(!localStorage.generator) {
    localStorage.generator = 0;
  }
  return localStorage.generator++;
}
```

Could people please comment if this code would run without any concurrency issues and generate unique IDs across multiple browser tabs hammering this `generateUniqueID` function?

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001112/is-localstorage-thread-safe) seems relevant. There's no specification for `++` that says it works any differently from `localStorage.generator = localStorage.generator + 1`, so there's no locking between reading and writing.

Comment: it uses a mutex internally just to ensure that localStorage stays consistent.

Comment: No, `++` is indeed not atomic. It's the same as writing `localStorage.generator = 1 + Number(localStorage.generator);`

Comment: @Barmar thank you for pointing to the other SO question, which references the mutex implementation [requirement] (https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#threads).

It seems that the mutex protects the entire event processing routine until the next one is taken from the event loop. This effectively gives me exclusive access to the entire localStorage for the duration of execution block. On the down side, other tabs would be frozen until this script finishes execution and returns to the browser's event loop.

Please correct me if I understand it wrong.

Comment: That does sound right. Although there's a link in that paragraph to a nonexistent location in the official spec.

Comment: But I wasn't able to reproduce that in our application that uses localStorage. I opened two windows, and each one was able to update a localStorage variable without causing the other to hang.

Comment: Hmm, strange, I am using chrome on macOS and can confirm that I cannot run a script on two tabs simultaneously trying to access *the same* localStorage.

Answer (score 3):

**[2023 Edit]**

Apparently (thanks @Jaka Jančar) the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-localstorage-attribute) has changed:

> The localStorage getter provides access to shared state. This specification does not define the interaction with other agent clusters in a multiprocess user agent, and authors are encouraged to assume that **there is no locking mechanism**. A site could, for instance, try to read the value of a key, increment its value, then write it back out, using the new value as a unique identifier for the session; if the site does this twice in two different browser windows at the same time, it might end up using the same "unique" identifier for both sessions, with potentially disastrous effects.

**[Original answer]**

According to W3C Web Storage Recommendation (see [here](http://w3.org/TR/webstorage/#threads)), §4.5 "Threads":

> Because of the use of the storage mutex, multiple browsing contexts will be able to access the local storage areas simultaneously in such a manner that scripts cannot detect any concurrent script execution.
>
> Thus, the length attribute of a Storage object, and the value of the various properties of that object, cannot change while a script is executing, other than in a way that is predictable by the script itself.

Which means to me is that the mutex is placed on first access (read or write) of the script to `localStorage` and kept until this event loop entry execution returns. **Effectively, we have exclusive access to the `localStorage` for the duration of the execution chain**.

I would imagine, if `await/async` are used, it would break the execution chain, and make the code executed across multiple event loop entries, thus breaking this contract. Even though the source code block looks monolithic. Beware.

The answer to the question is: Yes, the code in question would behave correctly, providing the browser keeps to the W3C recommendation. This is despite the fact that the "test" `if(!localStorage.generator)` and the "increment" `localStorage.generator++` are in the different lines and in most other execution environments are not guaranteed to execute atomically.

Comment: As it's only a recommendation, that seems to imply some need to detect when the browser doesn't follow the recommendation so code making assumptions about this doesn't break later...

Comment: @Michael, In most cases, it's a good strategy to develop assuming that the browser complies with W3C Recommendations, and if the testing reveals that there is a problem with a particular browser, make a decision on it separately. Perhaps you would find acceptable workaround, or maybe you would ban that browser all together. The browser developers should aim at making their browsers conformant to all W3C recommendations, really.

Comment: Note that this is no longer in the spec. Instead, it says the opposite: “[…] authors are encouraged to assume that there is no locking mechanism […]”.