# .push fail. Works without Local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot get the user input to push to Local Storage.
When my quizData variable is an empty array it works fine,

```
let quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz'));
```

and changing it back to this works because (I assume) there is already info in LS,

```
let quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz'));
```

but clearing LS will cause it to fail again.
Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated

```
let quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz'));
const addQuiz = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  let quizForm = {
    question: document.getElementById('question-input').value,
    a: document.getElementById('a-input').value,
    b: document.getElementById('b-input').value,
    c: document.getElementById('c-input').value,
    d: document.getElementById('d-input').value,
    correct: document.getElementById('correct-input').value,
  };

  quizData.push(quizForm);
  document.forms[0].reset();

  console.warn('added', { quizData });

  localStorage.setItem('MyQuiz', JSON.stringify(quizData));
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('submitForm').addEventListener('click', addQuiz);
  console.log(quizData);
});
```

and the error
custom-questions.js:26

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
at HTMLButtonElement.addQuiz

Comment: you need to retrieve within the handler, just accessing local storage once before declaring the listener is not adequate. Every time you set local storage it is a new JSON string, which will need to be retrieved and parsed on every `addQuiz` call. It's **not** a consistent array reference that can be held and pushed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `quizData` to a new array if there's nothing in the `localStorage`.

```
let quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz')) ?? [];
```

---

If `quizData` is updated elsewhere, it is better to retrieve the latest array before updating it. So you can get the latest `quizData` inside `addQuiz`.

```
const addQuiz = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  let quizForm = {
    question: document.getElementById('question-input').value,
    a: document.getElementById('a-input').value,
    b: document.getElementById('b-input').value,
    c: document.getElementById('c-input').value,
    d: document.getElementById('d-input').value,
    correct: document.getElementById('correct-input').value,
  };
  
  const quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz')) ?? [];

  quizData.push(quizForm);
  document.forms[0].reset();

  console.warn('added', { quizData });

  localStorage.setItem('MyQuiz', JSON.stringify(quizData));
};
```

Comment: @pilchard That's true. Updated the answer

Comment: Definitely more robust

Comment: @pilchard Actually, `localStorage` doesn't have to be retrieved every time. `quizData` is an array that gets mutated on every `addQuiz` call and `MyQuiz` is set to the updated array. So,  `quizData` always refers to the updated array.

Comment: I understand that, and it overwrites localstorage everytime. If that one reference is the only place it's ever edited it's fine, and even more efficient than parsing every time. Also, multiple tab support... [Is localStorage thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001112/is-localstorage-thread-safe)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize quizData as empty array if null or undefined.

```
let quizData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyQuiz')) || [];
```